# QGIS - How to find the distance for the nearest polygon from point for a defined angle?

Tags: qgis-3, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I'm using QGIS 3.1 and I want to find the distance from a point to the nearest polygon for a given direction. So for example, for each point in my point layer I want to find the distance to nearest polygons located to the south west of each point (225 degrees). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Add two fields to the points layer. One which represent the desired angle, and one representing the distance from the point to the extent of the polygon layer (to ensure the line is long enough to intersect all polygons).

**2)** Using QGIS plugin *Shape Tools*, create a *Line of Bearing* which begins at the point of interest, (choose the corresponding distance/azimuth fields from the points layer as input param). Be sure to select the *Add input geometry fields to output table* checkbox to retain the connection to the point.

[image]

[image]

**3)** Run Processing>Vector overlay>Intersection using the Line of Bearing output as the Input layer, and the Polygon layer as the output layer.

[image]

**4)** Run Processing>Vector geometry>Centroids and calculate the centroids of intersecting line segments.

**5)** Use Vector>Analysis Tools>Distance Matrix to compute the distance from the closest centroid to the parent point. (Be sure to choose the appropriate Id)

[image]

The Distance Matrix output contains the Point Id, along with the distance to the nearest polygon in the given direction.

[image]

[image]